# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt5, qwidget

I'm new to QT and I tried to create a Widget using the QT Designer.
I am now trying to connect buttons while also using inheritance to edit the Ui_Form class from another.

This is the main file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from HunterVsBoar import Ui_Form


class PythonGame(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(PythonGame, self):
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            super(PythonGame, self).__init__(parent)
            self.ui = Ui_Form()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

            self.attack_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.start_attack)
            self.heal_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.heal_hunter)
            self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.event_start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = PythonGame()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the converted ui file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):


    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1037, 885)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 819, 1031, 61))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.attack_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)

        self.attack_btn.setFont(font)
        self.attack_btn.setObjectName("attack_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.attack_btn)

        self.heal_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.heal_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.heal_btn.setObjectName("heal_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.heal_btn)

        self.dmg_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.dmg_btn.setObjectName("dmg_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.dmg_btn)

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1041, 311))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_2)

        self.textBrowser_1 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textBrowser_1.setObjectName("textBrowser_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_1)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 790, 131, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.hp_hunter = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form) 
        self.hp_hunter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 790, 118, 23))
        self.hp_hunter.setProperty("value", 100)
        self.hp_hunter.setObjectName("hp_hunter")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 770, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.hp_boar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
        self.hp_boar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 790, 118, 23))
        self.hp_boar.setProperty("value", 100)
        self.hp_boar.setObjectName("hp_boar")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(930, 770, 47, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.start_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 630, 75, 23))
        self.start_btn.setObjectName("start_btn")

        self.stop_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.stop_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 630, 75, 23))
        self.stop_btn.setObjectName("stop_btn")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Hunter vs Boar"))
        self.attack_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Attack"))
        self.heal_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Heal"))
        self.dmg_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Damage potion"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "What do you want to do?"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Hunter"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Boar"))
        self.start_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Start!"))
        self.stop_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Stop!"))
```

As soon as I launch main.py I receive the following error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

while the `Form = PythonGame()` is being marked.

Anyone able to help me out here? Like I said, I'm relatively new to programming in Python and also new to Stackoverflow so pls don't kill me if I did anything wrong lmao

(Oh and to clarify any confusion with the connect statements = These functions exist, I just deleted them out of this code because I think they're not important (because they're not the problem) )

Comment: Is the nested `__init__` a copy-paste error? if not, then here is your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looks like there are two swapped parameters.
Instead of:

```py
class PythonGame(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(PythonGame, self):
```

it should be:

```py
class PythonGame(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, PythonGame):
```

But `PythonGame` is your class name, probably it should not be there, no?
That would make it

```py
class PythonGame(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(PythonGame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.attack_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.start_attack)
        self.heal_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.heal_hunter)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.event_start)
```

Comment: I see no reason why `PythonGame` should be there at all. It should be `def __init__(self):`.

Comment: Hey there, I also realized that, and re-reading the initial code I saw that there were two levels of __init__ which I also removed from the latest code block.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is better after the edit. I commented on an earlier version.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! I hope I didn't make an idiot out of myself, lmao.

Comment: @David of course not, here is the right place to ask questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The `self` in `__init__()` is a reference to an instance of itself and is placed as the as the first argument of class methods. Additional arguments can be specified. In what you have, `PythonGame` is serving as what is traditionally `self` and it's looking at `self` as another parameter. Get rid of the `PythonGame` argument and you should be fine. Since it's a class method, it knows that it's part of `PythonGame`

```
def __init__(self):
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` function of `PythonGame` is wrong, it should be:

```py
class PythonGame(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
       self.ui = Ui_Form()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
       self.attack_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.start_attack)
       self.heal_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.heal_hunter)
       self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self, self.event_start)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer self method is incorrect. You should just pass self and any necessary parameters for any class attributes.

You're code should look like this:

```
class PythonGame(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
def __init__(self):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(PythonGame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```